Not able to read App.config file keys data in migrated unit test project
I migrated the unit test case project from dotnet 4.7 to 6.0. Build is getting succeeded, but while running the test case, I am getting error as "ArgumentException: Section [CustomConfig] is not handled by the NameValueSectionHandler". Same CustomeConfig is working in old project of 4.7 version. What can be the resolution of this issue?
I tried acccessing the value using Immediate Window using command System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationName"]
null
I am unable to find any solution.

In .NET Core, you should use the appsettings.json instead of the appsetting.config.
And you can use these to get info from the JSON:
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
var config = builder.Build();
var applicationName = config.GetSection("ApplicationName").Value;

